# MySQL Query keep numbers which do not fall between a range

Tags: mysql

Could anyone point me in the correct direction on how to do this SQL query?  I have two tables coord_table and rm_table.  I would like to perform a query where any coord_table.loc which falls between any rm_table.start_loc or rm_table.end_loc is removed from the result of the query.

```
    coord_table
    coord_id    loc
    ____________________
    1           9
    2           19
    3           30
    4           55

    rm_table
    rast_id start_loc   end_loc
    ___________________________
    1       10          20
    2       50          60

    query_result
    coord_id    loc
    _____________
    1           9
    3           30
```

Comment: Go on. Try something. And if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This should work. It uses the `BETWEEN` syntax:

```
SELECT a.* FROM coords_table a
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
      (
      SELECT
          coords_id, loc, start_loc, end_loc,
          (loc BETWEEN start_loc AND end_loc) as is_between
      FROM
          coords_table, rm_table
      ) a
  WHERE a.is_between = 1
  ) b
ON a.coords_id = b.coords_id
WHERE b.coords_id IS NULL
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3acdb/2

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. This doesn't give the exact solution but I was able to figure out the correct solution from this.  I needed a subquery.

Comment: This should work: **`SELECT a.* FROM coords_table a
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
      (
      SELECT
          coords_id, loc, start_loc, end_loc,
          (loc BETWEEN start_loc AND end_loc) as is_between
      FROM
          coords_table, rm_table
      ) a
  WHERE a.is_between = 1
  ) b
ON a.coords_id = b.coords_id
WHERE b.coords_id IS NULL`**  Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f500ce